# Listview populated from Strings.xml, how to theme it?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

so I have a list view setup the following way, not using an ArrayAdapter - how can i control how it looks?

the java file:

```
// Get ListView object from xml
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

the xml:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:entries="@array/catagory_arrays"
style="@style/AppTheme">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: you need a custom adapter

Comment: What all do you want to control?